# 3 way relationship in SQL?

Tags: sql, database

Say that I have an object named `person` which has (name, address, phone_number) as its attributions and an object named `dog` which has (ID, year_of_birth, breed). Then I have a relationship between the two objects named `owner`. `Owner` has the following attributions: (owner_id, pet_id).

On an E-R diagram `owner` would be a triangle connecting `dog` and `person` which are both rectangular. I'm giving this info just so you understand the relationship. my goal is to list the `dogs` ID's who's owners are from France.

I've tried the following an dozens of different combinations like this:

```
select id from owner where address = 'France';
```

Comment: I'm surprised you are so familiar with E-R diagrams and not at all familiar with `join`s.  Think about how you would use joins to bring the tables together to answer this question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to resist the urge to criticise your naming and also assume you actually have an ID field on the person table/object. Finally, this many to many structure allows for a pet/dog to be 'owned' by multiple persons. I would guess that this is a mistake and, if so, the whole mapping table is not required.

```
SELECT
  d.ID
FROM
  dog d INNER JOIN owner o
    ON d.ID = o.pet_id
  INNER JOIN person p
    ON o.owner_id = p.ID
WHERE
  p.address = 'France'
```

Comment: Listen to Zec, if a dog can only have 1 owner there is no need for the `Owner` table.

Comment: It is possible for a dog to have many owners. Think of a family. Most local councils don't see it this way but it really depends on the op's use case

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
SELECT Dog.*
FROM Dog
JOIN Owner ON Owner.DogId = Dog.Id
JOIN Person ON Person.Id = Owner.PersonId
WHERE Person.Address = 'france';
```